# Why am I getting this error "Reference to 'get' is ambiguous, both 'get()' and 'get(long, TimeUnit)' match"

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand why am I getting "Reference to 'get' is ambiguous, both 'get()' and 'get(long, TimeUnit)' match" error in the second code snippet, but not in the first one?

The method signature for assertThrows (jUnit5) is the following:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> T assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable);

// and executable is 

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Executable {
    void execute() throws Throwable;
}
```

Compiler does not complain here.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

  @Test
  void testOK() {
    Callable<String> callable = () -> {return "test";};

    FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
    new Thread(futureTask).start();

    assertThrows(ExecutionException.class, futureTask::get); // waits for thread to finish
  }
```

however here

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow;

@Test
  void testNotOK() {
    Callable<String> callable = () -> {return "test";};

    FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
    new Thread(futureTask).start();

    assertDoesNotThrow(futureTask::get); // waits for thread to finish
  }
```

the "futureTask::get" seems to be ambiguous here, both 'get()' and 'get(long, TimeUnit)' match, despite the fact that assertDoesNotThrow also accepts Executable as parameter.

```
    public static void assertDoesNotThrow(Executable executable);
```

I cannot understand why it works in first example, but does not in the second one.

What have I tried until now, mostly reading and googling, but I still do not get it :(

Comment: The answer to your question is "Because futureTask::get has multiple implementations" and it's more of a mystery why both are not failing.  In any case, write better code and provide something like a lambda that *explicitly* and *unambiguously* calls what you intend to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assertDoesNotThrow` also has this signature:

[`<T> assertDoesNotThrow(ThrowingSupplier<T> supplier)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.10.1/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertDoesNotThrow(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.ThrowingSupplier))

The message is wrong in that there *is* an ambiguity, but not the one the message explains. The ambiguity is: Should `f::get` be 'fitted' as being an instance of the `Executable` Single-Abstract-Method interface (SAM), or the `ThrowingSupplier` SAM - both can be done, thus, this is ambiguous.

You can 'fix' it by casting: instead of:

```
assertDoesNotThrow(futureTask::get);
```

you could write:

```
assertDoesNotThrow((Executable) futureTask::get);
```